# Do you need to see where you move a flaming sphere as a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, line-of-sight

Example: Cast the sphere then duck around a corner away from the fight and move it on each of your turns as a bonus action while staying safe and keeping concentration.

Flaming Sphere (PHB 242-243)

> A 5-foot-diameter Sphere of fire appears in an unoccupied space of your choice within range and lasts for the Duration. Any creature that ends its turn within 5 feet of the Sphere must make a Dexterity saving throw. The creature takes 2d6 fire damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.
>
> As a Bonus Action, you can move the Sphere up to 30 feet. If you ram the Sphere into a creature, that creature must make the saving throw against the sphere's damage, and the Sphere stops moving this turn.
>
> When you move the Sphere, you can direct it over barriers up to 5 feet tall and jump it across pits up to 10 feet wide. The Sphere ignites flammable Objects not being worn or carried, and it sheds bright light in a 20-foot radius and dim light for an additional 20 feet.
>
> At Higher Levels: When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 3rd Level or higher, the damage increases by 1d6 for each slot level above 2nd.

Do you need to be able to see where you want to move a flaming sphere to?

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Do you need to be able to see the Mage Hand to use it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76004)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No you don’t need to see where you are moving it

According to Jeremy Crawford:

> The text of the flaming sphere spell explains how the sphere interacts with barriers, creatures, and pits as it rolls around. As the caster, you don't have to see where you move it –January 25, 2018 SageAdvice.

This may be unofficial but it seems to back up the "spells do what they say they do" aspect of spell casting. Since there is no mention of moving it to "where you can see" it therefore doesn't need to be moved to where you can see.

Comment: Yes, and sageadvice.eu is *not* an official source of rules. It is simply a compiling of tweets and quotes from developers and other such people, the *only* official rules are those in the books and those found specifically in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf)

Comment: @Medix2 I wasn't previously aware of that so i made an edit to the answer.

Comment: To quote the Compendium: "Official rulings on how to interpret rules are made here in the Sage Advice Compendium by the game’s lead rules designer, Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford on Twitter). The public statements of the D&D team, or anyone else at Wizards of the Coast, are not official rulings; they are advice. Jeremy Crawford’s tweets are often a preview of rulings that will appear here."